# Substance to help cold patch adhere better?

Tags: adhesive, patch, asphalt

I moved into a house recently that has an unmaintained driveway.  It looks like it hasn't been sealcoated in 20 years.  I plan to use "cold patch" to fill one small pothole (4 inch diameter) and fill some low depressions that tend to become puddles when it rains.  Note that I have already pressure-washed the driveway and there are no crumbling bits present on the driveway.

Is there some substance I can put down on the old asphalt first, to help the cold patch adhere better?  For instance perhaps [Quikrete Concrete Bonding Adhesive](https://www.homedepot.com/p/Quikrete-1-Qt-Bonding-Adhesive-990214/100318541)?

Answer (score 3):

FWIW: I like to use the liquid crack filler for that purpose.  Pour/smear it around on the joining surfaces.

https://www.homedepot.com/p/Latex-ite-1-Gal-2X-Premium-Blacktop-Crack-Filler-2XCFC/100080909

Comment: yes, and heat up the "cold patch" so it is nice and sticky, then tamp it down really well. Some of the resealers require you to let patches "weather" prior to use...

Comment: @JimmyFix-it - How do you heat it up?

Comment: You lay it in the sun, at least; or use a weed-burner style torch...